# Adding privacy policy to custom ui on azure b2c app

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using custom policies on my Azure AD B2C app. And I am using a custom UI passing a reference to a UI hosted on my server like this on my sign-up/sign-in policy:

```xml
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>https://MyURL/index.html</LoadUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>
```

This is working. But now I want to add a HTML link element to my custom UI with the URL of my Privacy Policy and that element is not showing up when I execute my policy. Everything is showing up except that link.

Could it be some cache on Azure that is using the old custom UI? Or is something I'm missing?

Comment: Is the privacy policy URL inside or outside the "api" div?

Comment: The privacy policy URL is in my custom ui html. In the "https://MyURL/index.html"  file. I just want to add it below the sign in form on my custom signup/signin policy. Should I add it someway first in my custom policy definition?

Comment: Hi Germán, it still does not answer Chris's question whether the policy URL is inside or outside the div with id "api"? That is important to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div id="api">
    <!-- Leave this element empty because Azure AD B2C will insert content here. -->
</div>

<!-- URL goes here, outside of the API div above -->
<a href="/path/to/privacypolicy.html" target="_blank">Privacy policy</a>
```